# I am Trying to send mail after select yes or no option from input select box

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to add functionality to a form that will submit when a user selects an option containing value *yes* from a select list without using a submit button. Here is the link: http://juiceme.no/phpmail/.

```
<?php
//if "email" variable is filled out, send email
  if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))  {

  //Email information
  $admin_email = "syhunk835@gmail.com";
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
  $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
  $select = $_REQUEST['select'];

  //send email
  mail($admin_email, "$subject", $select, "From:" . $email);

  //Email response
  echo "Thank you for contacting us!";
  }

  //if "email" variable is not filled out, display the form
  else  {
?>

 <form method="post">
  Email: <input name="email" type="text" /><br />
  Subject: <input name="subject" type="text" /><br />
  Message:<br />
  <!--<textarea name="comment" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea><!-->
  <select id="select" name="select">
    <option value="yes">More View</option> 
    <option value="yes">Yes</option> 
    <option value="NO">No</option>
</select>
  <br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>

<?php
  }
?>
```

The problem is that I am not able to submit the form when a user selects the option containing *yes* in the select box.

Comment: use a conditional statement and checking if it is equal to something

Comment: btw, you tagged as javascript and angularjs and jquery with no code to support the question.

Comment: Ok, thanks for suggestion , I do not need submit button , conditional statement is does not fire a mail when value is selected@@ thanks  I am happy with your suggestion

Comment: do not know which of them dislike this question . this question make a point .I want say only one this for every one please do not in hurry.@@

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add this inline JS to your `select` dropdown,

```
onchange="if(this.value==='yes')this.form.submit()"
```

like:

```
<form method="post">

  Email: <input name="email" type="text" /><br />
  Subject: <input name="subject" type="text" /><br />
  Message:<br />

  <select id="select" name="select" onchange="if(this.value==='yes')this.form.submit()">
    <option value="yes">More View</option> 
    <option value="yes">Yes</option> 
    <option value="NO">No</option>
  </select>

</form>
```

[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/vedemol/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: Omg@@brilliant@ Thanks, let me check

Answer (score 0):

I would add an onchange handler (and remove the submit input). If they hit Yes, you can submit to the server where an e-mail can be generated and your empty form can be returned. If they hit No, you don't have to do anything (or you could clear the inputs so they can try again, perhaps).

You can get the value of your selection like this:

```
$('#select').on('change', function() {
  if (this.value === 'Yes') {
    // submit to server so we generate an email
  } else {
    // do nothing or clear inputs?
  }
})
```